# How to unit test classes within a WCF web service

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, mstest

How can I get a unit test project in a (VS2015) solution for a WCF web service to use the same web.config file for its own app.config? I don't want to have to replicate all the settings that are in web.config in my app.config (and have to remember to keep them in sync). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to shift the relevant settings to a separate config file using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35184374/4036688). One thing to remember is that paths are relative to the WhateverTests\bin\Debug folder when referring to the other config file in the Whatever project.